# Did Corbyn promise to write off UK student debts?

Tags: politics, united-kingdom

The way that ***I*** remember things might not actually be as they happened. I accept that. However, I am sure that I recall the UK Leader of the Opposition, [Jeremy Corbyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Corbyn), promising to scrap all student debt prior to the last UK election.

Now, a mere seven weeks after the election, in the [24th July Metro](https://www.metro.news/jeremy-corbyn-denies-misleading-student-voters/685098/) newspaper:

[image]

> "We didn't say we'd write off student debts"
>   JEREMY CORBIN insisted yesterday that he never promised to write of all student debt - despite saying he would 'deal with it' during the General Election campaign.
>   The Labour leader, shown by opninion polls to enjoy huge support among young people, told the BBC he was unaware of how much writing off loans would cost when he made his previous comments. He was accused by the Tories of 'betraying' graduates by backtracking.

I realize that politics is all weasel words, innuendos, double meanings and "[it depends what the meaning of the word 'is' is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4XT-l-_3y0)"

So, can anyone point to somewhere that Corbyn ***did*** actually say that?

Comment: You make some extra assumptions about the apparent effect of the supposed claim. We don't know for sure the extent of new young voters influence or whether the promise mattered to their vote. Sine nobody expected Labour to win (and, despite their joy at doing better than expected, they didn't), what they promised may be irrelevant.

Comment: I will delete the bit where I said "A promise which led to an unexpectedly high turn out of younger voters and an unexpectedly good result for labour.
". I agree that that is superfluous (+1).

Comment: My memory is that Corbyn earlier stated that he **wanted** to write off study debts, but that they would need to look at how to **cost it** before they could promise to do so.

Comment: Does anyone actually claim that Corbyn said that?  Your question does not cite such a claim.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question asks *Did Corbyn promise to write off UK student debts?* but does not cite any notable source claiming that he did in fact promise this.  You might ask this on [Politics.SE].

Comment: Metro is fairly credible (or can say why you do not consider to to be so?), and it's "Crobyn denies..." seems to make the claim that he said it

Comment: @gerrit could it be moved to politics, I've already answered it and thought I did ok. Why do we even have a politics tag? those questions degrade to tribal partisan arguments as fast as renewable energy questions do.

Comment: @Mawg I can see the claim that Corbyn denies having said it, but I do not see the counter-claim alleging that Corbyn *did* say it.

Comment: I think this is on-topic. (We had a meta-question about this issue once...) The Metro says the Tories say he backtracked. The Metro says Corbyn says he didn't backtrack. An answer could show any of: He did backtrack, he didn't backtrack, the Metro was wrong about the people making the claim.

Comment: [Here's the meta question I mentioned.](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/if-a-claim-is-commonly-accepted-does-questioning-it-require-a-notable-counter-c) - it wasn't as directly relevant as I remember it, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

The article headline seems like an answer to a strawman argument, I'd question who owns the paper that wrote it and what their political alignment is.

Corbyn said ["We will scrap tuition fees..."](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2017/may/21/labour-abolish-university-tuition-fees-jeremy-corbyn-eu-uk-europe), specifically on already indebted students he said he would look into ways to ["ameliorate that"](http://www.nme.com/news/jeremy-corbyn-will-deal-already-burdened-student-debt-2082478), some [reporter](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-40697326) later asks "Did you mean you wanted to write off all UK student debts?", he replies "nah I didn't say that, what a silly question", the headline becomes what you see in your question.

He said “We will scrap tuition fees and ensure universities have the resources they need to continue to provide a world-class education." as per the article, but the trick is this does not mean writing off current debt, the changes would be for future students.

Comment: I understand what you say, but do you happen to know if he did actually say that?

Comment: @Mawg scrapping tuition fees means not charging someone next year, it doesn't mean writing off charges made last year. This is the trick the reporter pulled. It would make as much sense as assuming that when the tertiary fees were reintroduced in Australia we would charge those that had previously graduated for free... actually that wouldn't be a bad idea

Comment: A good pint (+1). Can you point to what Corbyn actually said?

Comment: @Mawg http://www.nme.com/news/jeremy-corbyn-will-deal-already-burdened-student-debt-2082478 BBC said this interview was the source, he never says 'wipe off student debt'

Comment: I've added links to the interview where the headline is from, and the NME interview where is said he wanted to "deal with it" (•_•)-(-•_•) ⌐■-■- (⌐■_■)